# How to move Cardano Node stake pool to new IP address?

Tags: stake-pool

We are changing hosting services, and want to move the BP and Relay nodes to new machines.  They are all set up and synced with Mainnet, but when we re-run the 05c SPOS script it complains there are no funds on the wallet address.  We shouldn't have to pay the registration fee again.  All we want to do is update the IP addresses of the Relay Nodes on the network.  All of the keys are moved over to the new servers, and the topology file is updated.

We did some searches and found some articles, but nothing that was helpful.

The command we ran is from the keys folder:

`05c_regStakepoolCert.sh myPool myWallet REREG`

It says:

`No funds on the Source Address!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to pay the 500 ADA registration fee, but you do have to pay the regular transaction fee since updating a pool registration must be submitted via a regular transaction.

If all you are doing in this transaction is submitting a pool cert, it should cost you somewhere around 200,000 Lovelaces (0.2 ADA). Just make sure the new pool cert has the new IP addresses.

Pro tip: if you purchase a domain name (say, `mypool-rocks.com`), you can actually avoid having to resubmit pool certs every time you change IPs. Instead, you can point your pool certs at a DNS address (i.e. `relay1.mypool-rocks.com` and `relay2.mypool-rocks.com`), and use a DNS resolver like Google to point your IPs at those respective sub-domains. This works great for moving IPs around, just make sure that your security is tight with whatever DNS resolver you choose.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense.  FYI, I added 1A to my wallet, and that was insufficient.  It then proceeded to list the amount needed, which adds up to 1196433 Lovelaces:  196433 for TxIn/TxOut, 196433 for re-registration, and 803567 for being returned to payment address...  Makes sense we have to have funds to pay the tx fee.

Comment: I don't think the second 196433 fee is for re-registration. As far as I am aware there is no "re-registration" fee. However, there is a minimum UTXO value of 1 ADA (meaning every UTXO on Cardano must have at least 1 ADA or 1000000 Lovelaces in it - which is exactly what should be sent back to you as change.

Comment: I will say I had 1A in the wallet and it said not enough funds, but when I had 2A it worked.  Thanks again!